# Angular 5: custom async validator freezes browsers

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, angular-promise, angular-validation

I've a **custom async validator** that **freezes** my app. Tested in **Chrome and Firefox**.

It happens after typing approx. 30 chars, which means the [Validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) was **called approx. 30 times**.

Looks like the Validator doesn't get destroyed and holds the **memory**.

```
# my.component.ts
// ...
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email], EmailTakenValidator(myApiService)], 
});


# email-taken.validator.ts
import { ValidatorFn, AbstractControl, Validator } from '@angular/forms';
import { RegistrationService } from '../services/myApiService';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export function EmailTakenValidator(myApiService:MyApiService) {    
    return control => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {               
        if (!control.value || !RegExp(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/).test(control.value)) {
            // invalid email -> skip
            return resolve({ EmailTakenValidator: {value: control.value} })
        }  

        myApiService.emailTaken(control.value).subscribe(isTaken => {
            if (isTaken) {
                return resolve({ EmailTakenValidator: {value: control.value} })
            } else {
                return resolve(null);
            }
        }, () => {
            return resolve({ EmailTakenValidator: {value: control.value} })
        })       
    })
}
```

I checked the code without the `myApiService`, still the same problem.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** It seems to be the memory. I just provoked the error and ignored the frozen browser for a while. The used memory increased from 210 mb to 470 mb!

Comment: If you only omit the `myApiService` call without adding any code, then the promise will never be resolved. Can you confirm that `emailTaken` works as expected, i.e. emits a single value and completes? FWIW: `return resolve(` should be just `resolve(`, `RegExp(/` should be just `/`.

Comment: @abetteroliver thanks for your answer! `emailTaken` works as expected. Only problem is that it freezes after a few calls.

Comment: @abetteroliver I removed the `return`s and `RegExp`. Still the same problem.

Comment: Can you try unsubscribing from the `emailTaken` call?

Comment: @bc1105 it's probably something like this, but it's the same error even if I comment the whole `myApiService` part. I tested the Validator promise with only `resolve(null);` inside - same error.

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem with the code from the example. There has to be something else in your component that's relevant.

Comment: @abetteroliver Thanks for trying. I'll have a closer look on the big picture. :-)